# Escrever dentro de uma DIV utilizando CSS

Tags: css

Como **escrevo dentro de uma DIV** utilizando CSS. Abaixo tenho o CSS e neste mesmo código gostaria de **escrever uma frase** para aparecer nesta **DIV**.

```
.gerenciar-coluna-exibicao-vismodelo{    
        position:relative;
        height:60px;
        width:250px;      
        float:left;
        text-align:left;
        line-height:70px;
        border: 0px double #cccccc;
        text-indent:25px;
        background-color:#FF3F42;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        color:#1085A9;
    }
```

Sem que com isso eu precise ir na TAG da DIV e escrever o que preciso.

Comment: Você quer mudar o texto conteúdo da div via css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz assim

```
.gerenciar-coluna-exibicao-vismodelo:before {
  content: "Boschini was here!";
}
```

Porem o recomendado seria vc fazer por jquery.

Comment: Porque? pode ser incompatível com alguns navegadores?

Comment: IE8+ suporta, mas é meio gambiarra isso viu, eu acredito que por JS seria o ideal.
mas funciona

Comment: Qlq navegador com suporte a CSS2